# Autoincrementing a field till a certain condition is met mysql

Tags: mysql

I have the following table

```
SNo Value Item
```

where Sno is a column which exists in another table also. Right now , what I need is a self incrementing field which will go on incrementing if the value of sno is a constant and then get back to 0 and start incrementing again once the value of sno changes. IS there any way to do this?

Lets say I have four columns:

```
SNO |Value |Item | AUtoIncrementingField
1    344      a            0 
1    345      b            1 
1    346      c            2 
2    568      d            0
```

So when I say insert into this table , and the value of SNO changes from whatr it originally was the value of the auto incrementing field should go back to 0. Is there any inbuilt way of doing this, or writing some code on top of mysql to achieve this. If not what other option do I have to uniquely identify each value/item belonging to a certain value of sno?

Comment: What storage engine does this table use?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/11321211

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whilst this doesn't help you on InnoDB, it's worth pointing out that MyISAM natively supports this functionality. As documented under [Using `AUTO_INCREMENT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/example-auto-increment.html):

> #### MyISAM Notes
>
> For `MyISAM` tables, you can specify `AUTO_INCREMENT` on a secondary column in a multiple-column index. In this case, the generated value for the `AUTO_INCREMENT` column is calculated as [`MAX(auto_increment_column) + 1 WHERE prefix=given-prefix`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/group-by-functions.html#function_max). This is useful when you want to put data into ordered groups.
>
> ```
> CREATE TABLE animals (
>     grp ENUM('fish','mammal','bird') NOT NULL,
>     id MEDIUMINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
>     name CHAR(30) NOT NULL,
>     PRIMARY KEY (grp,id)
> ) ENGINE=MyISAM;
>
> INSERT INTO animals (grp,name) VALUES
>     ('mammal','dog'),('mammal','cat'),
>     ('bird','penguin'),('fish','lax'),('mammal','whale'),
>     ('bird','ostrich');
>
> SELECT * FROM animals ORDER BY grp,id;
> ```
>
> Which returns:
>
> ```
> +--------+----+---------+
> | grp    | id | name    |
> +--------+----+---------+
> | fish   |  1 | lax     |
> | mammal |  1 | dog     |
> | mammal |  2 | cat     |
> | mammal |  3 | whale   |
> | bird   |  1 | penguin |
> | bird   |  2 | ostrich |
> +--------+----+---------+
> ```
>
> In this case (when the `AUTO_INCREMENT` column is part of a multiple-column index), `AUTO_INCREMENT` values are reused if you delete the row with the biggest `AUTO_INCREMENT` value in any group. This happens even for `MyISAM` tables, for which `AUTO_INCREMENT` values normally are not reused.